# Stringify HTML button

Tags: javascript, json, onclick, stringify

I am trying to stringify an HTML element so that I can store it in a JSON dictionary. The problem is the element has an onclick event and I NEED to store the onclick event as well. However, when you add onclick events through javascript, they dont appear in the html. How can a stringify an html button

Here is how my code looks (in a basic sense)

```
btn = document.getElementById("my-button")
obj = {elem: btn.innerHTML}
JSON.stringify(obj)
*** deleted btn ***
```

Then when I reload the html element from the JSON string, the onclick event is gone.

For reference, my full site is: turtle-pond.com
The real problem: When you add an event to the calendar and then reload the page, the event loses its onclick attribute

EDIT: The button is deleted before it is reload.

Comment: `he onclick event is gone` innerHTML doesn't include the tag attributes (like onclick for example) - outerHTML does - but you'll need to do some other code refactoring

Answer (score 0):

```
btn = document.getElementById("my-button")
id = 'my-button'
obj = {elem: id}
str = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

when you need this dom,

```
dom = document.getElementById(JSON.parse(str).elem)
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify this before, but this seems to only work if the button is still on the page. By reloading the page, I mean the button is gone. I am trying to recreate the element from the JSON